# How to get the column with the lowest number of na cells in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and some of them has a lot of `nan`. How can I select the column with the lowest number of `nan` cells ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of idxmin() for minimum value.

df.isna().sum().idxmin() --to get the sum of lowest NaN values columns
or
df.isna().idxmin() --to get column with lowest Nan

Comment: I hope it solved your question.

Comment: Yes `df.isna().sum().idxmin()` is what I was looking for. Thanks